# QGIS VERSION 3.0, Pie diagram showing same values for all districts

Tags: qgis, chart

I wish to make a pie diagram for the districts, for total male and total female for each district however after following all the correct steps, the values of the pie charts are the same in all the districts.

[image]

enter image description here[image: pie chart for assam districts]

Comment: As of now, you've showed only the `size` tab of the diagram settings. Please post a screensot of the `attribute` tab as well as it is there where you define the sectorial size of the pies.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. The link here will show you the attribute table values. Thank you! (^_^) https://drive.google.com/file/d/13k7d9paO8_K7CnfvAnm6K1sJLwrlNc8f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ek8BIxrmNBTn144rf4tpGF4JHtsj3DHe?usp=sharing these are the screen grabs of all the options